# How to store the response generated from an api call to the mysql database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, api, payment

I am new to understanding the coding languages and have started to learn things using wordpress.
    I am trying to integrate a payment gateway and could generate the access_token and refresh_token which i need to store the same into my database for making further api calls for payments and user data updation.

The following is my code to run to generate tokens.
    Please help as to how to store the token values in database.
    I have tried replicating the wordpress register code to insert values, but 
    could not succeed.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once "page-signup.php";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://test.instamojo.com/oauth2/token/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  
    "client_id=gC4z8rBV55SDiavZobpvZCcanwK3mbnY
    &client_secret=dYFbCXaX9WUy1c3kkCXV8JRJkTxmLcxCXwncVKWlWsh8c0QOI
    5Uz30PCzOieC879RT7PLsEwrRKZDvZXqYpF5fZiE2Z62z3dly7p7ZUbGHTmOWmBsh3
    &grant_type=password
    &username=$username
    &password=$password",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      ),
      ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {

    $json_decode=json_decode($response,true);
    $refresh_token=$json_decode['refresh_token'];
    $access_token=$json_decode['access_token'];
      }


    echo $response;


     ?>
```

Comment: Please can you clarifyng me: the code you posted returns a json value like {token: this_is_your_token} and you want to store 'this_is_your_token' in the wordpress db to use later?

Comment: yes, Stefano. it generates a token like you mentioned and the response is added here below for your reference.   {"access_token": "t1Hah9VSyRhUYoi4HQwNvWgAo3NrmQ", "expires_in": 36000, "token_type": "Bearer", "scope": "read write payouts:read payments:read payments:fulfil payments:refund", "refresh_token": "aaFY0ijGiZtjRNxnwzToBfaTmqh6hN"}  and i need to use the tokens later by retrieving from the database. I am also trying to understand how to retrieve. I have created two fields for the above in wp_user table.... not too sure if i am right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to store and retrieve this info from wordpress db is to use the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API): with only one command you can store, retrieve and delete the token. 
Normally the wordpress options uses a [normalized array](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169035/what-are-these-entries-in-the-database-looks-similar-to-json/169036#169036) but you can also store directly a json token or simply a string.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, for the information. However, I need to further dig deep and understand the said concepts as i do not have knowledge on the usage of the same.

Comment: It's very easy: just 
add_option( $option, $value);
delete_option( $option );
get_option( $option);

Comment: Thanks Stefano, will try doing it. I actually tried placing the whole line in the functions.php of the child theme.... probably the reason why it did not work or is it that i need to place the line in the above code ...?

Comment: I tried adding the lines to the code but could not figure out the values in the database. may be i am not keying the right option name...

Comment: Thanks Stefano, I could get the access_token stored in database using username as option. I have added two lines the other for refresh token, but could not find the values in the database.... what is the right format for storing the refresh_token value ( i mean multiple option values)

Comment: HI Stefano, I could store the access_token and refresh_token using different option names. Trying to understand if the access_token & refresh_token stored will apply to the relevant user when we use get_option while updating the user details and making a payment link....will the id generated during the signup works as an identifier...?

Comment: The option is stored with its name and does not depend from the user; you can use the username to buid the option name if you want to retrieve a user-depended value. (Do not kwon if this answer to you question... I hope so)

Comment: True Stefano, I want to retrieve user specific values while i make a request to update user data / create a payment link. Is it possible to do that and if so, what is code that i need to use. and also that i am not able to store two values with the same username option for option name... is there a way to do that and also that this process is being run after a user is registered and logged in...so i think username or user id could be aligned with the value... but do not know how to do that... please help.